# Limiting directory browsing in SYSTEM-DIALOG GET-FILE

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

My Progress 11.6 application is using the SYSTEM-DIALOG GET-FILE command to allow the user to select a file:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE cFilename AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE lResult AS LOGICAL NO-UNDO.

SYSTEM-DIALOG GET-FILE 
    cFilename
    FILTERS "Text Files (*.txt)" "*.txt",
            "All Files (*.*)" "*.*"
    DEFAULT-EXTENSION ".txt"
    MUST-EXIST
    RETURN-TO-START-DIR
    TITLE "Select File"
    USE-FILENAME
    UPDATE lResult.
```

The problem is the users can navigate to anywhere in the Windows file system. Is there a way to limit the navigation, perhaps only letting them go up to the start-in directory but not beyond?

Answer (score 2):

system-dialog uses OS dialogs. Setting security should be done on the OS. 
By doing this on OS level the security applies to all applications the user has access to.

If your application needs a file from a certain directory you should validate the lResult after the dialog returns.

Answer (score 1):

System-dialog (and their options get-file or get-dir) have no mention as far as security goes in documentation. I believe you'd have to limit access through the OS permissions or write your own, in this case.